# Нет отклика от MySQL на Ubuntu Server (виртуальная машина)

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu, virtualbox

Раздал инет с телефона. Подключил домашний ноут к этой раздаче.

Установил Ubuntu Server 16 x32 на ноут (Win8) в виде виртуальной машины в Oracle VM VirtualBox.

Настройки сети этой виртуальной машины:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запускаю виртуальную машину с установленным Ubuntu Server и смотрю с помощью команды

```
ip a
```

ip данного сервера. Допустим он указан как 123.456.7.89

Установил на сервер MySQL Server

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Разрешил удаленный доступ в MySQL

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation utility
```

Запустил firewall и добавил разрешение для MySQL

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw allow mysql
```

В файле **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf** поменял bind-address

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

Зашел в MySQL, создал БД и указал на нее разрешение доступа

```
mysql -u root -p
CREATE DATABASE test
GRANT ALL ON test.* TO someuser@'PUBLIC IPV4 ADDRESS' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';
```

соответственно 'PUBLIC IPV4 ADDRESS' это публичный IP второго компа (Win10) с которого хочу подключаться к БД test. Этот комп подключен к домашней WiFi сети.

На втором компе запускаю Py код

```
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='123.456.7.89',
    user='someuser',
    passwd='some_password'
)

mycursor = db.cursor()
mycursor.execute('SHOW DATABASE')
```

и получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pese\PycharmProjects\MySQL_twt\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 574, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pese\PycharmProjects\MySQL_twt\test_1.py", line 3, in <module>
    db = mysql.connector.connect(
  File "C:\Users\pese\PycharmProjects\MySQL_twt\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 273, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pese\PycharmProjects\MySQL_twt\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pese\PycharmProjects\MySQL_twt\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1003, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\pese\PycharmProjects\MySQL_twt\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 350, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\pese\PycharmProjects\MySQL_twt\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 576, in open_connection
    raise errors.InterfaceError(
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on '123.456.7.89:3306' (10060 Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера)
```

Пробую со второго компа через консоль пингануть мой сервер:

```
ping 123.456.7.89
```

ответ со 100% потерь:

```
Обмен пакетами с 123.456.7.89 по с 32 байтами данных:
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.

Статистика Ping для 123.456.7.89:
    Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 0, потеряно = 4
    (100% потерь)
```

Comment: Покажите первое число в IP-адресе хотя бы?

Comment: Первые три цифры IP - 192

Comment: Можете временно выключить фаервол для проверки.

Comment: `Запустил firewall` — зачем??? это же не ms/windows. // вообще похоже на проблемы с маршрутизацией пакетов. если сами не можете определить, в этом ли причина, приводите значения ip/маска для обоих участвующих в обмене пакетами систем.

Comment: @ГеннадийП
Отключил через

`sudo ufw disable`

Далее удостоверился что он **inactive** с помощью команды

`sudo ufw status`

К сожалению по прежнему не пингуется(((